# The css rule from data attribute is not getting applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, escaping

I am stuck.  PLEASE explain if you vote this question down so I can understand why, and how and improve my questions.
   I have a data-attribute that needs to be "referenced" by jquery. This data attribute is being referenced by jquery to set the "background" and "url" to a css class.  Im not sure how or where to place the quotes so the quotes inside the url() are placed correctly. (which I believe is the problem)

```
<li class="wings-data" data-country-code="se" 
 data-background-style="'background','url( "images/se.jpg")'">

var backgroundStyle = $(".wings-data").data("background-style");

$("#article").css(backgroundStyle);
```

Comment: Im not sure why SO would not let the <li> tags be placed in the question or why all the code was not placed in the "code area"  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminate quotes at all for more readable code.

HTML :

```
<li class="wings-data" data-country-code="se"
 data-background-style="background,url(images/se.jpg)"> ABC</li>
```

JS :

```
var backgroundStyle = $(".wings-data").data("backgroundStyle").split(',');
$("#article").css(backgroundStyle[0],backgroundStyle[1]);
```

See the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2C6fB/288/) solution.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the quick responses.  I do not have 15 rep points yet or i would have pushed "up" .  Zakaria Acharkis' answer is the only one that worked for me in this case.  I would like to know why the escaping of characters didn't work for me if anyone has an idea. (It seems like it should have).

Answer (score 2):

```
<li class="wings-data" data-country-code="se"
 data-background-style="'background','url( \"images/se.jpg\")'"> ABC</li>
```

And

```
var backgroundStyle = $(".wings-data").prop("data-background-style");
$("#article").css(backgroundStyle);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you get the data, background-style is changed into `backgroundStyle`; **jQuery will automatically strip hyphens and camel-case hyphenated attributes**.

```
var backgroundStyle = $(".wings-data").data("backgroundStyle");
```

also, escape the quotes with backslash :

```
<li class="wings-data" data-country-code="se"
 data-background-style="'background','url( \"images/se.jpg\")'"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in your code

```
var backgroundStyle = $(".wings-data").data("background-style");

$("#article").css(backgroundStyle);
```

**Instead of this try code**

```
li class="wings-data" data-country-code="se"
 data-background-style="'background','url( \"images/se.jpg\")'"

var backgroundStyle = $(".wings-data").attr("data-background-style");

$("#article").css(backgroundStyle);
```